# Convert Unsigned Long to String ^

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

How do you convert an unsigned long to a String ^?

I've tried

```
String ^ mystring = marshal_as<String ^>(myunsignedlong)
```

but it doesnt work!

Comment: Is this C++? `String ^` does not seem.

Comment: C++/CLI. `String ^` is a managed .NET string.

Comment: It's C++/CLI -- Microsoft's language for writing managed code in C++.  The `^` is a pointer to a managed object, in this case .NET's String.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"unsigned long" is an alias for System::UInt32 in a C++/CLI program.  Use its ToString() method:

```
unsigned long value = 42;
String^ txt = value.ToString();
```

or use its overloads to use a non-default format or culture.  Or use String::Format() for many more composite formatting options:

```
String^ txt = String::Format("The value is {0}", value);
```